# How can I download a file from my Jhipster application via REST?

Tags: java, spring, pdf, jhipster

I have developed an app using Jhipster, I have a method to download a file from my application. When I run this method via api REST, the file is downloaded successfully, but if I press the button in my application to download, that doesn't work and debugging all is OK.
Their logs are the same:

> log via http://localhost:9060/api/ticket-download

```
2019-04-12 19:20:51.971 DEBUG 940 --- [  XNIO-6 task-6] c.g.aop.logging.LoggingAspect            : Enter: com.app.web.rest.TicketResource.downloadFile() with argument[s] = []
2019-04-12 19:20:51.973 DEBUG 940 --- [  XNIO-6 task-6] c.g.aop.logging.LoggingAspect            : Exit: com.app.web.rest.TicketResource.downloadFile() with result = <200 OK,Byte array resource [resource loaded from byte array],{Content-Disposition=[attachment; filename=ticket.pdf], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], Content-Length=[92672], Content-Type=[application/pdf]}>
```

> log via application

```
2019-04-12 19:23:43.341 DEBUG 940 --- [  XNIO-6 task-7] c.g.aop.logging.LoggingAspect            : Enter: com.app.web.rest.TicketResource.downloadFile() with argument[s] = []
2019-04-12 19:23:43.343 DEBUG 940 --- [  XNIO-6 task-7] c.g.aop.logging.LoggingAspect            : Exit: com.app.web.rest.TicketResource.downloadFile() with result = <200 OK,Byte array resource [resource loaded from byte array],{Content-Disposition=[attachment; filename=ticket.pdf], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], Content-Length=[92672], Content-Type=[application/pdf]}>
```

> TicketResource.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TicketResource {

    @GetMapping("/ticket-download")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFile() {
        File file = new File("D:/Tickets/ticket.pdf");

        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        header.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=ticket.pdf");
        header.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        header.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        header.add("Expires", "0");

        Path path = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
        ByteArrayResource resource;
        try {
            resource = new ByteArrayResource(Files.readAllBytes(path));
            return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(header).contentLength(file.length())
                    .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf")).body(resource);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like that by clicking on the "download" button in my application, the file will be downloaded correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to modify the `service.component.ts` and the `ticket.component.ts` to work with the Resource response. I advise you use the `FileSaver` library. Here is an example for Angular download file with Spring Boot that can be helpful for what you have to do: http://roufid.com/angular-download-file-spring-boot/

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to Spring, but you attach the code for the download controller, but not the one where the download actually happen.

The file is actually created?

The path exist (all the directory of the path exist)?

**EDIT:**
*I haven't realize he talk about a web application, not swing or javafx, so the previus code was useless. Sorry.*

Maybe the function is incomplete, try something like this:

```
downloadFile(): Observable<any> {

return this.http
   .get(SERVER_API_URL + 'api/ticket-download')
   .subscribe((data) => {

       this.blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});

       var downloadURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.blob);

       window.open(downloadUrl);
});
```

Or use the **FileSaver** library.

Comment: The file and path exist, I already said that the file is downloaded well through the api REST.

Comment: I mean, when you click on the "download" button, the file is created on disk?

Comment: No, the file is created previously in another method, which generates it well. The problem is to download.

Comment: The code you posted provide the file, but you have **not** posted the one which actually execute the download.

If the REST call work, the problem is in the download function.

Comment: I only have this method to download, we are going to ignore the method that generates the pdf. I want download that File from the computer, this method via REST is well, but via app doesnt work, the download window does not appear

Comment: Yes, i get that already. I wanto to know how the controller work! The click on the button what function trigger.

Comment: Button calls a angular function `downloadFile(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(SERVER_API_URL + 'api/ticket-download');
    }`

Comment: Edited my answer, look if is usefull.